# Raven Index not fetching a document

Tags: indexing, lucene, ravendb

I have a Web app which fetches record from ravendb by executing an index.

The issue is that raven index is not fetching a particular record / document and hence it is not showing up on the UI. When I export / import the database in my local machine and fire the index, I can see that particular record. But for some reason, the index is not fetching this record in PROD. Its not a case of stale index as the record was submitted a couple of days back and records submitted after this record are getting fetched by the index.

Any thoughts anyone please?

Comment: What happens if you update this record?

Comment: How quickly are you retrieving the data from inserting it into the store? Are you instantly retrieving from the index moments after inserting the record?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but have tried browsing the collection in PROD and verified that the record exists there?